Matplotlib freezing for no reason. What am I doing wrong
I'm trying to draw an interactive matplotlib figure in Tkinter. I've taken the slider_demo https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html and tried encapsulating it in FigureCanvasTkAgg. The code runs correctly but if I move the sliders several times (alternating between the two) the program hangs????
To try and understand the problem, I took the original demo and made the following changes: all the plotting code has been encapsulated in a plot_sin() function and in main I just call this function and do a plt.show(). But I have the exact same problem as explained above. Therefore, the problem doesn't seem to be related to the plot integration in tkinter, but to something else I don't understand.
Maybe someone can tell me what I've done wrong.
I have added my test code.
commented at the end is the code to test in Tkinter (same problem)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg  # type: ignore[misc]
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


def plot_sin():
    def f(t, amplitude, frequency):
        return amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * t)

    t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
    init_a = 5
    init_f = 3
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    (line,) = ax.plot(t, f(t, init_a, init_f), lw=2)
    ax.set_xlabel("Time [s]")
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
    axfreq = fig.add_axes((0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03))
    freq_slider = Slider(ax=axfreq, label="Freq", valmin=0.1, valmax=30, valinit=init_f)
    axamp = fig.add_axes((0.1, 0.25, 0.0225, 0.63))
    amp_slider = Slider(
        ax=axamp,
        label="Amplitude",
        valmin=0,
        valmax=10,
        valinit=init_a,
        orientation="vertical",
    )

    def update(val):
        line.set_ydata(f(t, amp_slider.val, freq_slider.val))
        # fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    freq_slider.on_changed(update)
    amp_slider.on_changed(update)
    return fig


fig = plot_sin()

# to display in tkinter comment next line and uncomment following
plt.show()

# root = tk.Tk()
# root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)
# canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
# # canvas.draw()
# canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
# root.mainloop()


Further test: I've added a print to the update function (callback for sliders) and the messages don't appear in the console. It's only when I stop the program that all the prints appear. So it seems that a certain number of messages are stored in a buffer and when it overflows the program freezes?
